# Is there a way to calculate the minimum width and height of a viewbox so that all the drawing could fit inside it?

Tags: html, css, svg

If there are several shapes and paths in the drawing, and if all these paths should be visible without any cropping, the viewbox must encapsulate everything in it. However, just by looking at the svg document (xml text), is there a way to determine the numbers min-x, min-y, width and height needed to get a tight crop around the drawing?

Comment: get the bounding box of all the shapes and construct the viewBox to fix.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, get a reference to the `<svg>` element, and call the `getBBox()` function.  It will return the values you need.  However you may need to add a little extra around the ouside to account for stroke width markers etc.